# Activities menu is not working

Tags: display, activities-overview

When I press the super key I can search for applications but open applications is not shrinking.

As you can see in this image this is what happens when I click the super button.

[image: As you can see in this image this is what happens when I click the super button]

Comment: Have you installed any Gnome extensions? MAybe one of them is causing this behaviour.

Comment: There was an update in the some of the extensions so i turned off the extensions. It seems one of the extensions did it. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: For anyone having the same problem. "Workspaces to Dock" extension is caused this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably one of your Gnome Extensions is causing the problem. Try disabling them one by one until you find the culprit.

Then it would be good to file a bug report to help the developers.